# How to set one password for all net users in cmd for batch script?

Tags: script, batch-file, cmd.exe

Im writing a windows batch script and I need to set all the users to a certain password? I know that I can do `net user` to see all users on the computer and I can do `net user username password` to set the password of a user. But Is there a way to combine these two commands to set all the users to a specific passwords.

Comment: No; Could write a powershell script that performed a loop and at each user, set the password, but there is no command because setting severe username to the same password is a horrible security practice it means anyone can log into any account with that password

Comment: Could also make a quick list of usernames to a text file each line will be a different user name and then a quick batch `FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN (FileList.txt) DO net user %~F password`

Comment: Can I do "net user >> user.txt" and then run the above command?

Answer (score 0):

> Setting several username to the same password is a **horrible security
>   practice**. It means anyone can log into any account with that
>   password – [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)

However, next batch code snippet shows a way how-to get active user list. As soon as you remove `ECHO` from 6th line, you can see if it works with `net` command (could require administrator privileges and run elevated):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
FOR /F "TOKENS=2* delims==" %%G IN ('
        wmic USERACCOUNT where "status='OK'" get name/value  2^>NUL
    ') DO for %%g in (%%~G) do (
            ECHO net user %%~g
          )
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%%G` to retrieve the active user `name` value;
- `%%g` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned: `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`).

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL` special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)